# Nested If statement, Index or VLookup or VB Code in a Macro?

Tags: if-statement, nested

I am an intermediate Excel user and I can figure things out 95% of the time but for some reason, this one escapes me. I have tried IF, IFS, INDEX, VLOOKUP. I have also looked up creating VB code to run a Macro to do this. I know the codes I have below will not work, I was not expecting them to the way they are but this is the way I'm trying to explain what I am trying to do. I have Googled the issue and read my Advanced Excel books but I am stumped. It is probably something so simple but I need to ask for help on this one.

I have 3 columns. Column A contains either UGRD or PBAC. Column B has number that is inputted by the user. Column C needs to be a function that works something like this:

=if(A1="UGRD" and if B1<=30, "1st Year Undergrad", B1<59.9 and >=30.1, "2nd Year Undergrad", B1<=89.9 and >=60, "3rd Year Undergrad", TRUE, "4th Year undergrad" else
=if(A1="PBAC" and if B1<=36, "1st Year Master", TRUE, "2nd Year Master"

Example: if column A says UGRD, and column B says 17, then I need the formula to calculate that this is a 1st Year Undergrad